# How to set a network interface to promiscuous mode in a kernel module?

Tags: linux, networking, module, kernel

I developed a kernel module to get all packts that bypass and ethernet interface.

Now i want in my module, set that interface to a promiscuous mode. How i can do that?

I get the interface using dev_get_by_name(&init_net,"eth0") to a struct net_device *dev.

Best Regards

Comment: What [have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I tried to change the flags in the struct net_device to IFF_PROMISC but didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following function (which is found in net/core/dev.c):

```
int dev_set_promiscuity(struct net_device *dev, int inc)
```

If you want to set the device in promiscous mode `inc` must be 1. To unset promiscous mode, set `inc` to -1. For the function to work you need to have the rtnl lock. To get it you need to call the following functions before and after the call to `dev_set_promiscuity()` (functions found in net/core/rtnetlink.c):

```
void rtnl_lock(void);
void rtnl_unlock(void);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dev_set_promiscuity()`. Use an increment of 1 to set the device to promiscuous mode, -1 to set it to non-promiscuous mode.

Comment: That function increments a variable (uc_promisc if i'm right). When i iniciate my module, i used dev_set_promiscuity(dev_eth0,1) to activate and when i remove the module i used dev_set_promiscuity(dev_eth0,-1) desactivate. I think the promiscuous mode is all time active and appear some messages  like "eth0:promiscuity touches roof, set promiscuity failed, promiscuity feature of device might be broken".

Comment: Impressive. Are you sure you used `dev_set_promiscuity(dev_eth0,1)`? Then it must have been called 2 billion times.

Comment: Yes. I just call it twice, the first one when i iniciate my module, and the last one when i remove my module with inc -1. If i reboot the pc, the uc_promisc will be reset to default? I will check again my code if isn't here any loop that i mess up. Thank you. Btw can you help me on other topic? :) Regards

Answer (score 0):

When i use dev_set_promiscuity(dev_eth0,1) it appears on dmesg command this:

> [  550.411935] RTNL: assertion failed at net/core/dev.c (4059)
>
> [  550.411940] Pid: 5164, comm: insmod Tainted: P            2.6.35101
>
> [  550.411943] Call Trace:
>
> [  550.411951]  [] ? printk+0x25/0x29
>
> [  550.411956]  [] __dev_set_promiscuity+0x37/0x127
>
> [  550.411960]  [] dev_set_promiscuity+0x18/0x37
>
> [  550.411965]  [] ? hook_init+0x0/0x88 [nethook]
>
> [  550.411969]  [] hook_init+0x3a/0x88 [nethook]
>
> [  550.411973]  [] do_one_initcall+0x4f/0x139
>
> [  550.411978]  [] ? blocking_notifier_call_chain+0x11/0x13
>
> [  550.411982]  [] sys_init_module+0x7f/0x19b
>
> [  550.411986]  [] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
>
> [  550.411989] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode

RTNL: assertion failed at net/core/dev.c (4059) this occurs and after a while appear some bug reports and kernel crashes.

Someone know how to solve this? Best Regards